# Gauss Seidel Formula Derivation Matrix Forming

Tags: functional-analysis, numerical-linear-algebra

I decompose the matrix $A$ of size $n \times n$ into $D = diag(a_{i,i})$, $L$ is the lower triangular matrix with $0's$ elements in the diagonal, similarly $D$ is the upper triangular matrix with $0$'s in the diagonal such that:

$$
A = -L + D - U
$$

So I rewrite the linear system $Ax = b$ as $x = (D-L)^{-1} U x + (D-L)^{-1}b$
$$
T(x) := (D-L)^{-1} U x + (D-L)^{-1}b
$$

Denote $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, $x_{m+1} = T(x_{m})$, $x_m =(x_{m}^{(1)},..,x_{m}^{(n)})$

I am trying to derive the Gauss Seidel formula of the form $x_{m+1}^{(j)}$:

I rewrite this as an iteration problem:

$$
x_{m+1} = (D-L)^{-1} U x_{m} + (D-L)^{-1}b
$$

Then  I solve for relation of each element. However, I am stuck at computing the  inverse $(D-L)^{-1}$. I solved this with a matrix of size $3\times 3$ first to  see the recurrence. The only recurrence I get is the diagonal element in this matrix is of the form $\frac{1}{a_{ii}}$. How can I deduce the other elements  in this inverse matrix?

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**:

You need to use the triangular structure of $(D-L)$ and $U$ a lot.

First, set $y=Ux_m+b$. Then we have $x_{m+1}=(D-L)^{-1} y$.

For $x_{m+1}^{(1)}$, we have the formula
$$
x_{m+1}^{(1)} = \frac{1}{a_{11}} y^{(1)}.
$$
For $x_{m+1}^{(2)}$, we have
$$
x_{m+1}^{(2)} = \frac{1}{a_{22}} (y^{(2)}- a_{21} x_{m+1}^{(1)},
$$
which works well because you already have calculated $x_{m+1}^{(1)}$.
For the higher components, it works similarly.

When expressing $y$ in the final formula, you also have to use the triangular structure
of $U$.